# batch script, renaming a xml file inside a folder

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch file whereby I can rename a xml file name inside a folder on my Desktop.

- prompt the user to key in the file name
- if the file name is found, it will then prompt the user to key in an existing xml file name
- if  an existing xml file name, it will then prompt the user to key in a new xml file name

an overview of my contents inside a file name(bb).

[image: file]

this is my batch-script

```
  @echo off
set /p fn=Enter Folder name:  
if exist C:\Users\roberts\Desktop\%fn% (
    set /p oldxmlname=Enter a old xml file name: 
    if exist C:\Users\roberts\Desktop\%fn%\%oldxmlname%.xml (
        set /p newxmlname=Enter a new xml file name:
        ren C:\Users\roberts\Desktop\%oldxmlname%.xml %newxmlname%.xml
        echo file name changed successfully.
    )
)else (
    echo folder not found in path.
    echo C:\Users\roberts\Desktop\%fn%
)
```

this is my output. The file name didn't change at all.

[image: output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered. The same comment goes for the `REN`.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

And if an `ELSE` clause is used, the `IF`-true command **must** be `(parenthesised)`, and the <kbd>)</kbd> and <kbd>ELSE</kbd> **must** be on the same physical line. If `ELSE`-true command is `(parenthesised)`, the `ELSE` and `(` **must** be on the same physical line. There **must** be a <kbd>Space</kbd> either side of the `else` keyword.

---

A demonstration:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
cls
set var=ORIGINAL
echo Start value of var=%var%
for %%i in (1) do (SET var=AFTER
ECHO var is %var% in the for loop
)
echo Final value of var=%var%
ENDLOCAL
ECHO.
echo ---- try again with ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
ECHO. 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set var=ORIGINAL
echo Start value of var=%var%
for %%i in (1) do (SET var=AFTER
ECHO var is %var% not !var! in the for loop
ECHO Note: in the loop VAR has old value %var% and new value !var!
)
echo Final value of var=%var%
endlocal
```

Note how the value of `var` is interpreted differently depending on the use of `setlocal` or `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`. The `!var!` syntax is only available in `delayedexpansion` mode and accesses the value of `var` as it is modified in the block,

Comment: sorry I don't really get what you mean. because it's my first time writing a batch file.but  I do noticed something, the first time edit my filename eg(from b to z), the filename doesn't change. now if I type b ,the filename is not found. now I have to type z(from z to b) again then it will change the filename from b to z

Answer (score 1):

You left `\%fn%` out of the `ren` command, so the file you're asking to rename really doesn't exist.

You want `ren C:\Users\roberts\Desktop\%fn%\%oldxmlname%.xml %newxmlname%.xml`

Comment: thank you. I noticed something, the first time edit my filename eg(from b to z), the filename doesn't change. now if I type b ,the filename is not found. now I have to type z(from z to b) again then it will change the filename from b to z

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that doesn't need delayed expansion, which your code does.
When changing a variable and using it within a loop, then delayed expansion is required.

There are some quotes to protect long file/path elements and an added backslash to detect a path and not a file.

```
  @echo off
set /p fn=Enter Folder name:  
if not exist "C:\Users\roberts\Desktop\%fn%\" (
   echo The engines canna take the strain captain, try again!
   goto :EOF
 )

    set /p oldxmlname=Enter a old xml file name: 
    if not exist "C:\Users\roberts\Desktop\%fn%\%oldxmlname%.xml" (
    echo folder not found in path.
    echo "C:\Users\roberts\Desktop\%fn%"
    goto :EOF
    )

        set /p newxmlname=Enter a new xml file name:
        ren "C:\Users\roberts\Desktop\%oldxmlname%.xml" "%newxmlname%.xml"
           if not errorlevel 1 (
                   echo file name changed successfully.
             ) else (
                   echo oops!  Something is fubar
           )
```